# Look up table in linux+swap

Tags: linux, image, time

we write an image processing program in c++ that starts with making a 16MB look up table in Ram and we want it to be in Ram as long as our program is running!
when we test in windows 7:making LUT takes approximately 4 seconds and reading from LUT and filling to matrices takes **7 microseconds**.

But we have to run the software in Linux ,the results are confusing 
making LUT takes approximately 3 seconds but reading from LUT and filling to matrices takes **30 milliseconds** !!!

we guess it's because the LUT moves to swap !

do you have any idea ?or if our guess is true is there anyway to keep LUT in ram in Linux ?!

Answer (score 0):

`mlock(2)` will lock a segment of process space in RAM.

Comment: Not 16mb unless you.use root.

Comment: try what you suggested but nothings changed :( maybe it's not because of swap !